# I have a project in flutter to integrate API of ChatGPT, I create the UI and all things, but when I'm trying to generate the text I've got errors

Tags: flutter, dart, openai-api

This is my code: I don't know why when I run it and trying to click "Get Destination Suggestion" there are errors and no output response from ChatGPT; I'm trying and doing my best but nothing is achieved.

```
// Importing the 'dart:convert' library for encoding and decoding JSON data
import 'dart:convert';
// Importing the Flutter framework
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
// Importing the 'http' library as 'http' for making HTTP requests
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
// The main function, the entry point of the Dart program
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
// A stateless widget for the entire application
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  // The build method constructs the UI of the app
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // App title
      title: 'Travel Advisor App',
      // App theme configuration
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // The home page of the app is an instance of the TravelAdvisor widget
      home: TravelAdvisor(),
    );
  }
}
// A stateful widget for the main functionality of the app
class TravelAdvisor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  // Creating the state for the TravelAdvisor widget
  _TravelAdvisorState createState() => _TravelAdvisorState();
}
// The state class for the TravelAdvisor widget
class _TravelAdvisorState extends State<TravelAdvisor> {
  // Variables to store user input and API response
  int budget = 0;
  List<String> selectedInterests = [];
  String destinationSuggestion = '';
  // A list of predefined interests for the user to select from
  final List<String> allInterests = [
    'Beaches',
    'Mountains',
    'Historical Sites',
    'Adventure',
    'Shopping',
  ];
  // A method to send a request to the ChatGPT API and get destination suggestions
  Future<void> getDestinationSuggestion() async {
  String apiKey = dotenv.env['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']!;
  String url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions';
  try {
    // Making a POST request to the ChatGPT API
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      // Headers including content type and authorization
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey',
      },
      // Sending user input to the API as JSON
      body: jsonEncode({
        'model': "text-davinci-003",
        'prompt': 'Recommend a place to visit that offers...',
        'max_tokens': 100,
        'temperature': 0.5,
        'stop': ['Human:', 'AI:'],
      }),
    );
    // Retrieving and handling the API response
    final responseBody = response.body;
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      // Parsing the JSON response
      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(responseBody);
      // Updating the UI with the destination suggestion
      setState(() {
        destinationSuggestion = data['destination'];
      });
    } else {
      // Printing an error message if the API request fails
      print('Error: $statusCode - ${response.reasonPhrase}');
      print('Response Body: $responseBody');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Printing an error message if there's an exception
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
  @override
  // Building the UI of the TravelAdvisor widget
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Setting the background color of the scaffold
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 222, 229, 243),
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Setting the background color of the app bar
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 175, 231, 231),
        // App bar title
        title: Text('Travel Advisor'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        // Adding padding to the entire body
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        // Column widget to organize UI elements vertically
        child: Column(
          // Aligning widgets to the top of the column
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          // Stretching widgets horizontally to fill the entire width
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          // List of UI elements/widgets
          children: <Widget>[
            // Text field for entering the budget
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (value) {
                // Updating the budget variable when the text changes
                setState(() {
                  budget = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your budget'),
            ),
            // Adding vertical space between widgets
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Text widget for displaying information
            Text('Select your interests:'),
            // Column widget for displaying checkboxes for each interest
            Column(
              children: allInterests.map((interest) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(interest),
                  // Checking if the interest is selected
                  value: selectedInterests.contains(interest),
                  // Handling the change in checkbox state
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    if (value != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (value) {
                          selectedInterests.add(interest);
                        } else {
                          selectedInterests.remove(interest);
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            // Adding vertical space between widgets
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Elevated button for triggering the API request
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Calling the method to get destination suggestions
                getDestinationSuggestion();
              },
              // Button text
              child: Text('Get Destination Suggestion'),
            ),
            // Adding vertical space between widgets
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Text widget for displaying the destination suggestion
            Text(
              'Destination Suggestion: $destinationSuggestion',
              // Styling the text with a font size
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```